# Can Visual Studio profiling be based on execution time only?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I am using the profiler from VS2012 Ultimate, with the 'Instrumentation' option for timing.
My problem is that it reports functions doing the most work, which end up being the functions that are executed most often, not the the slowest, which is not very helpful.

For example, the Hot Path lists items with Elapsed inclusive time being high %, but the Elapsed Exclusive Time is 0%. I want to only filter by Exclusive Time and actual ms time and not %.
Functions doing the most Individual Work are Exclusive time % which is better, but I still only care about the Individual Exclusive time (ms) with maybe the slowest times listed in the hot path.

If I go into function details I can find average execution time, specifically exclusive which lists the slowest function taking .5 ms on average.
This might seem good, but I also know that the .5 ms average means that from 1000 samples, maybe 900+ take no time at all and a handful might take a second or more.

so, is there a way to have the VS2012 profiler, to look at only execution time, and not just the averages but also the worst case time so I can trace what is actually slowing it down.

VS2012 highlights lines of code based the % of call, can I also range this highlighting and all hot-path information to be based on (ms) time and not sample percentages?

Also, if VS cannot do this kind of profiling, but another program can with VS I would very much like to know about it.

Thank you.

Comment: Suppose there is a function that takes 10 msecs, which is called once, and another function which takes only 1 msec, but it is called millions of times. Which is worse?

Comment: Exactly, for me the 10 ms function is worse because the 1 ms is already as fast as it can get, but the one time the 10 ms function runs the program freezes (yes I am counting 1 sec and 10 sec) Either way, I think the option to pick how you want to look at it is most important.

Comment: In some cases, the best way to optimize is not to make the slow method faster, but to make sure you don't need to call it as often.

Comment: Absolutely, I have greatly reduced execution time and the number of calls to the slow functions, but they need to be used once in a while. Now I need more precise data about which path is slow in the worst case and try to speed it up or take it out.